# Precalculus algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I need to solve this problem and I don’t know how:

if $x + \frac 1y = y + \frac 1z = z + \frac 1x$, then $x=y=z$ or $x^2y^2z^2 = 1.$

I don’t need a full solution -- just a hint -- because I really don’t know what to do here.  I tried to make a system like

$xy + 1 = ky ,$
$zy + 1 = zk ,$
$xz + 1 = xk .$

Then I tried to add and subtract different equations in different ways, but I don’t know if I am even going in the right direction, so I’d appreciate a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Try to get something like $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)(xyz+1)(xyz-1)=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}$$ it's
$$yz(x-y)=y-z.$$
Similarly,
$$zx(y-z)=z-x$$ and
$$xy(z-x)=x-y.$$
Now, if $x=y$ so $y=z$ and we obtain $x=y=z.$

Let $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\neq0.$

Thus, $$x^2y^2z^2(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$$ or
$$x^2y^2z^2=1.$$